# Web-To-Lead throwing ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit error

Tags: governorlimits

We are getting ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit error on some of the Web-To-Lead creations.
It used to occur rarely before but has become more frequent now, have had 3 of such incidents in the past week.

Any kind of help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't one simple answer to this.

This error occurs when you have too many apex requests running concurrently for a longer period of time.

It's hard to tell what exactly is causing it (most likely it's trigger that runs on the Lead object in parallel with a lot of other apex requests) but I would suggest you to fine tune some of your apex code in the org.

For an example try to make batch apex jobs run at different times. If you have any integrations with 3rd party systems you might want to build some sort of queue and process records in bulk, optimise your triggers and use @future (or the new queueable interface) where possible for non real-time crucial operations. Also if you're executing batches from apex, try to fine tune them to process less records if possible to reduce the execution time.

Comment: I was thinking of the same, thanks for affirming my belief!